# Python Output in localhost even after defining app route to '/hello'

Tags: python, flask

Here's the code:-

```
from flask import Flask
app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world() :
    return 'hello World'

app.add_url_rule('/','hello','hello_world')
if __name__== '__main__': 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Please see if u can find an error, please type the correct code in the answer

Comment: What error? What are you trying to achieve vs actually happening?

Comment: output appears on localhost:5000 rather than localhost:5000/hello , as it should.pls see if u can help...

Answer (score 0):

Please see documentation for add_url_rule, required method name instead you will give in string format for

```
 'hello_world', hello_world
```

```
from flask import Flask
app= Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return 'hello World'

app.add_url_rule('/','hello', hello_world)

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```